Elasticsearch - Logstash Grok new field date formate is string and not date
I have a scenario where Logstash uses Grok to split the message into different fields. One field, message_date, is extracted and sent to Elasticsearch.
Right now the type of message_date in Elasticsearch/Kibana is string instead of date.
The index mapping setting is "dynamic": true.
The date string in the message looks like this yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS
and the grok filter is
grok {
    match => { "message" => ['%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:message_date} %{GREEDYDATA:message}'] }
}

I need to find a way to change the type to string in Elasticsearch or last case in Logstash.

By default, date detection is enabled on the Elasticsearch side.
The default patterns that are recognized automatically are
"dynamic_date_formats": [ "strict_date_optional_time","yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z||yyyy/MM/dd Z"]

You now have two options:
A. You modify your Logstash config to massage your date value into one of those supported formats
B. You modify the dynamic_date_formats to include your specific date format when creating your index:
PUT <your-index>
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_date_formats": [
      "strict_date_optional_time",
      "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z||yyyy/MM/dd Z",
      "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"
    ]
  }
}

The last date pattern will recognize your date format and a date field will be created instead of a text one

I am looking to apply the date formate to the new field message_date would this work for that?

Yes, using option B
